# How to make a virtual folder in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I got this code for usernames like mysite.com/username

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

- My users can submit posts. And my file for posts is topic.php which is also in root directory. If I rewrite topic.php, code thinks that it's a username.
  I need a folder like mysite.com/watch/topic.php but I want to make it like folder doesn't exists (virtualy) but I can access the topics through that URL.

Sorry for my bad english. thank you.

Comment: You definitely need somebody to help you with formulating the question -- it is unclear for me what you want to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^watch/(.+)/?$ $1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

It will rewrite all requests for files in your 'virtual directory' (watch) to files in your root folder. The 'L' behind the rule makes sure it will be the last rewrite for the request.

If the requested page is not in the 'virtual directory', it will assume the user is requesting a user profile, so it will rewrite the request to the user profile you specified

On a side note: I think you should change the profile request to something like

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Maybe now you think this is not neccesary, but in the future when you are trying to implement more rewrites, this enables you to distinguish what the user is actually requesting.